# ImportError: cannot import name myVar

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using a python calendar front end for a python script that performs a count down. I can print to terminal the string from a variable in the front end and it is in the format that I want to use, namely:

```
(12/10/14  12:00:00, %m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S)
```

The trouble I am having is when I substitute (ccDateTime) for (12/10/14)
in the count down script.

In the count down script I tried

```
from frontEnd import ccDateTime
```

then I get an

```
ImportError: cannot import name ccDateTime
```

When I try

```
from frontEnd import *
```

I get

```
NameError: name 'ccDateTime' is not defined
```

I also tried to pass

```
frontEnd.ccDateTime
```

No luck

I am using python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04

The calendar front end uses a class to create the Date and Time variables, while the count down is a script with no classes.

This is driving me nutz (short trip)
How do I pass the string variable to the count down script from the calendar front end?

frontEnd.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# todo ->pass date & time values
import datetime
import Tkinter as tk  # for Python 2.7
from Tkinter import *
import gtk

class PyApp(gtk.Window):

def __init__(self):
    super(PyApp, self).__init__()


    self.set_title("Set Crew Change Clock")
    self.set_size_request(300, 450)
    self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
    self.set_border_width(2)

    self.cal_label = gtk.Label("Click on Crew Change Date")
    self.colon = gtk.Label()
    self.colon.set_markup("<b> : </b>")
    self.time_label = gtk.Label("Set Crew Change Time")

    hour_adj=gtk.Adjustment(12, 0, 23, 1, 0, 0)
    self.hour = gtk.SpinButton(hour_adj, 0,0)

    min_adj=gtk.Adjustment(0, 0, 59, 1, 0, 0)
    self.minute = gtk.SpinButton(min_adj, 0, 0)
    self.minute.set_text('{:02d}'.format(int(min_adj.get_value())))

    # put the start button code here
    self.start_button = gtk.Button(label="Start Crew Change Clock")
    self.start_button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_click)

    calendar = gtk.Calendar() 
    calendar.connect("day_selected", self.on_day_selected)

    fix = gtk.Fixed()
    fix.put(calendar, 20, 20)
    fix.put(self.cal_label, 75, 230)
    fix.put(self.hour, 81, 275)
    fix.put(self.colon, 150, 278)
    fix.put(self.minute, 172, 275)
    fix.put(self.time_label, 85, 325)
    fix.put(self.start_button, 70, 370)

    self.add(fix)

    self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    self.show_all()

def on_day_selected(self, widget):
    (year, month, day) = widget.get_date()
    self.cal_label.set_label(str(month+1) + "/" + str(day) + "/" + str(year))


def on_button_click(self, command):
    if __name__ == "__main__":


        ccDate = self.cal_label.get_text()
        ccTime = self.hour.get_text() + ":" + self.minute.get_text() + ":00"
        ccDateTime = str(ccDate + "  " + ccTime)


PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

ccClock.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# displays Crew Change Clock
# needs date and time of crew change passed from cc_front

import datetime
import Tkinter as tk  # for Python 2.7
from Tkinter import *
from frontEnd import ccDateTime

san65 = ('Sans', 65)

def countdown(label):
  def clock():

crewChange = datetime.datetime.strptime(ccDateTime, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
remaining = crewChange-datetime.datetime.now()
days = remaining.days
hours = int(remaining.seconds) // 3600
minutes = int(remaining.seconds % 3600) // 60
seconds = int(remaining.seconds % 60)
displayFormat = 'Crew Change \n \n \n \n {} days \n \n \n \n {}:{}:{}'.format(days, hours, format(minutes, '02d'), format(seconds, '02d'))
label.config(text= ' {}'.format(displayFormat))
label.after(1000, clock)

clock()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Crew Change Clock")
logo = PhotoImage(file="cc3.ppm")
label = tk.Label(root, compound=CENTER, font=san65, image=logo, fg="red", bg='black')
countdown(label)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Clearly, `frontEnd` *does not define that name*. Are you sure you are importing the right module?

Comment: The front end is named frontEnd.py and creates frontEnd.pyc in the same folder as the front end and the count down clock

Comment: And what is *in* that module? Where is `ccDateTime` defined in that module?

Comment: You are only defining ccDateTime at such times as the button gets clicked, meaning it does not exist when you import the module.  I am not sure of what your ccClock.py module is trying to do with it to offer suggestions on how to refactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I pass the string variable to the count down script from the calendar front end?

One way of doing this is to have a hidden attribute that will hold the information that you need to pass. Depending on your need, this can be a standalone object, a class `Cctime` that has a data attribute maybe `__cctime` which will hold some information. Each time you need to pass info, create an instance of that class, and pass that object to the other class. This gives you accountability, and security. Each object is unique, and you can audit. Like passing little notes around on coloured paper.

Another way is to keep it in a class attribute in your class that will hold the info when you ask it to. It can be reset to default every time after you have passed the info. It can be accessed using `ClassName.attribute` the usual way, if you don't need audit. In your present code, you seem to be facing a scoping issue on that attribute as pointed out.

Finally, an `ImportError` frequently vanishes if your `os.getcwd` matches the directory where your script is.

Cheers.

Comment: This sounds like the way to go. Thanks for the help! Time to RTFM on class's

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to import a variable that is defined inside a function. I don't think that can be done. 
Define it outside the function and it can be imported. What is the purpose of the  "if **name** == "**main**":"  inside on_button_click() ?

frontEnd.py

```
ccDateTime = ""


def on_button_click(self, command):
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        ccDate = self.cal_label.get_text()
        ccTime = self.hour.get_text() + ":" + self.minute.get_text() + ":00"
        global ccDateTime
        ccDateTime = str(ccDate + "  " + ccTime)
```

ccClock.py

```
from frontEnd import ccDateTime

print(ccDateTime)
```

Comment: There have been a lot of modifications of the code. Kinda like throwing darts and seeing what would stick like global. The print statement was to see if the output was in the correct format and if it would print in the terminal. I used "if name=="main" to link ccClock to frontEnd. it has been more of a shotgun approach to programming.

Comment: I think you should remove __name__ == "__main__ - I don't think it has any purpose inside of a function. I could be wrong, but I think the only use is to conditionally execute code that is not inside function or class definitions - execute if the program being executed is this file, don't execute if being imported. But none of the code inside a function gets executed on an import.